# Configuration syncronization not importing everything

Tags: configuration

I have a remote server which I initially setup with a default Drupal **8.7.7** install.  I have since been building the site on my local development server and would now like to transfer the developments to the remote server.

I exported the configuration using `drush config:export`

I committed the the exported items to git and pushed them to the remote server.  I then ran `composer install --no-dev` followed by `drush updb` on the remote server and logged in.
I then went to the configuration synchronization setting and clicked on the import all button.

Everything seems to be working fine however 12 items will not sync.  I have tried importing them via the import -> single item option and tried importing everything via `drush cim`, however the following items still will not sync and show no errors:
[image]

I have repeated the process a number of times to check it wasn't a one off error.

The only similarity I can see is that they are all *core.entity_view_display* settings apart from the *one core.entity_form_display* item.  Each one has different differences.

How can I debug why these items won't syncronize?

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though the issue I had relates to this issue: **Display mode configurations don't get updated with new fields** https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2915036

I haven't tried the patch yet, but after saving the individual display modes the fields then get put into the export and sync properly.